# How do I turn a list of timestamps into a list of strings?

Tags: string, compare, datetimeindex

I have a list of dates that are datetime64 objects. I want to compare these dates to a larger list of dates that are in string format:

```
large_list = ['2019-12-30', '2019-12-31', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'] #etc...
smaller_list = [2019-12-30 00:00:00, 2019-12-31 00:00:00, 2020-01-01 00:00:00] #etc..
```

is there any way I can convert the smaller list into a list of strings similar to the larger list so that I can compare the respective dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
smaller_list = [ str(each_date) [:-9] for each_date in smaller_list]
```

it will become similar to the larger_list

Another work around will be to convert strings to date and then compare them for that you may look in here.

https://opensource.com/article/18/4/python-datetime-libraries

Comment: there is no space after str(each_date)